# publishing and recieving bigger messages using MQTT

Tags: android, publish-subscribe, mqtt, paho

I'm trying to test out my android application which uses MQTT to receive messages. I receive the message as JSON which also contains a base64 encoded image.
this works perfectly fine when the image is a few kilobytes , but when I try to send anything around 400KB the messages doesn't get sent.

I've used two public brokers both times got the same response. (test.mosquitto.org & iot.eclipse.org)

here's the JSON object being sent:

```
public void send() {
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
try {
    obj.put("isFormat", Boolean.valueOf(true));
    obj.put("title", "this is a title");
    obj.put("image", "(insert base64 encoded image here)");
    obj.put("imageExtension", "png");
    obj.put("body", "<p>body</p>");
} catch (JSONException e) {
}
```

here's the code used to publish , using Paho android service client:

```
client.publish(topic,obj.toString().getBytes(),Constants.QoS_ACK,false,null,null);
```

Comment: Does it work with a non-mosquitto public broker like broker.mqttdashboard.com?

Comment: How are you sending the message?

Comment: I tried broker.mqttdashboard.com but for an unkown reason i could never connect to it to begin with so i gave up.

Answer (score 0):

I think MQTT might not be comfortable with you sending the image within the JSON and you also doing a toString() which I doubt will help to encode back the image. 
try sending the image seperately and then bundle it with the json at reception. This should work!